# logstash-input-mongodb: controlling the output?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, logstash

I'm trying to setup the [logstash-input-mongodb](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb) plugin to read audits from my database, but all the parsing strategies seem to have issues and I don't see how to customize anything.

The "flatten" parse_method works quite nicely, but it ignores mongodb object IDs and does not output them anywhere except in the log_entry field.

The "simple" parse_method includes object IDs but outputs dates in a way that I cannot figure out how to parse with the date filter (e.g., "2017-02-12 16:30:00 UTC"). Then, in the absence of a proper timestamp, the plugin seems to generate timestamps on its own which have no relation to the current time (e.g., in 2022).

The "dig" method I haven't quite figured out yet.

So my questions:

- Is there a way to parse data from the log_entry (see example below) field that the plugin outputs? I've tried the json filter but it is not json because it's been ruby-formatted.
- Or, is there any way to get the "flatten" method to include object IDs?
- Or, is there anyw ay to get the "simple" method to properly format mongodb ISODate fields?
- Is there any way to prevent the plugin from reading data from the beginning of time (I only want to push the last day or so into logstash)?

Can be reproduced with any configuration, here's my basic one:

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
    placeholder_db_dir => '/elk/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'auditcommunications'
    batch_size => 1000
    parse_method => "flatten"
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
  }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Example data including log_entry:

```
{
        "audit-id" => "58a2edc916e057270065fa74",
         "created" => "2017-02-14T11:45:13Z",
            "type" => "mongodb-audit",
      "audit-type" => "PaymentAudit",
        "mongo_id" => "58a2edc916e057270065fa74",
       "expiresAt" => "2017-05-15T11:45:13Z",
     "lastUpdated" => "2017-02-14T11:45:13Z",
      "@timestamp" => 2017-02-14T11:45:13.000Z,
       "log_entry" => "{\"_id\"=>BSON::ObjectId('58a2edc916e057270065fa74'), \"order\"=>BSON::ObjectId('a8a2f205790858970046aa59'), \"_type\"=>\"PaymentAudit\", \"lastUpdated\"=>2017-02-14 11:45:13 UTC, \"created\"=>2017-02-14 11:45:13 UTC, \"payment\"=>BSON::ObjectId('58a2edc02eafcd560101ee5f'), \"organization\"=>BSON::ObjectId('56edde0ba33e1c03ff54a5ec'), \"status\"=>\"succeeded\", \"context\"=>{\"type\"=>\"order\", \"id\"=>BSON::ObjectId('58a2e205790852270046ab59')}, \"expiresAt\"=>2017-05-15 11:45:13 UTC, \"__v\"=>0}",
         "logdate" => "2017-02-14T11:45:13+00:00",
             "__v" => 0,
        "@version" => "1",
    "context_type" => "order",
          "status" => "succeeded",
       "timestamp" => "2017-02-14T11:45:13Z"
}
```

How can I extract the organization from the log_entry field above?

I've tried the following:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('organization', eval(event.get('[log_entry]')))"
  }
}
```

but this throws a rubyexception: **ERROR logstash.filters.ruby - Ruby exception occurred: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER**

Comment: Can you share your logstash configuration?

Comment: @Val added it. I've tried playing with it in many ways and nothing seems to make a difference, so I don't think it's so relevant.

Comment: Concerning the fourth point, have you tried using the `since_*` settings?

Comment: Concerning the first point, I suggest using the `ruby` filter and `eval` the `log_entry` field.

Comment: @Val regarding the since_*, I don't see anywhere in there where you can add an actual ID or timestamp to start from. It looks like it just allows you to configure which column/table/type to use but it will always start from the beginning of time

Comment: It will keep the cursor of where you are in a local SQLite DB and start from there the next time, to prevent restarting from the beginning.

Comment: @Val thanks for the ruby filter tip, I'll have a look at it (I guess that means I have to learn ruby?). Could you give a simple sample of how to pull a field out of a JSON-like structure with this filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135655/discussion-between-joniba-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `simple` parse_method then you can parse the timestamp easily with the following pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ` that you can add to your date filter.

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ" ]
  }
}
```

Regarding the last point, I suggest checking the `since_*` settings which allow you to keep a cursor of what's been already processed and only start from that cursor on the next logstash restart.

Comment: So again, I don't understand how the since_* settings help prevent processing of ancient entries? Could you show an example? And the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" is not working for me for the dates being returned by the simple parse method (like "2017-02-12 16:30:00 UTC"). I'm getting the _dateparsefailure tag.

Comment: I've modified my answer to make the date pattern work. I'll follow up with the since stuff

Comment: thanks, the date filter seems to work. I messed with it for forever and didn't get it to work. I added a sample output with a "log_entry" field. Any idea how I can parse the object IDs out of it? One way or another, whether I'm using simple or flatten, I can see that I'm going to have to learn to extract data from this field.

Comment: What if you add `unpack_mongo_id => true` in your config?

Comment: If you see the `logstash_sqlite.db` file, you could use the [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)  in order to modify the `place` value in the  `logstash_since_auditcommunications` table

Comment: about the sqlite.db, yes, that's what I've been doing. Pretty hacky though :(

Comment: Well, you're initially supposed to set it up properly before starting to pull. Now what you want to do it to make sure to start at some point in history, so that's hacky anyway ;-)

Comment: Well if/when he moves the plugin to work with the oplog tail, it will work just fine. I don't think it's an unusual requirement at all. The unpack_mongo_id only works on the _id field.